# jquery lightbox plugin group of images effect

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-plugins, php-5.3

http://www.leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/ sample

---

so i have get images in while loop here is my code

```
<td id="gallery">

<a href='<?=$path ?>'>
 <img width="50" height="50" src=<?php echo $path; ?> />
 </a>

</td>


 $(function() {
            $('#gallery a').lightBox();
        });
    </script>
```

when i click first image light box effect works fine but when i click second image light box effect does n't work please guide me

Thanks for Advance

Comment: Try to create an example and post it here. I don't see anything wrong with your code, yet.

Comment: ok it's my link:http://ifliptips.com/admin/VueGuides/RegisterUsers.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you have multiple `<td id="gallery"`. You shouldn't use the same id for multiple elements, because $('#gallery') would always return the first one, but also because it's wrong!

Either move it into the table: `<table id="gallery"`,

or change it to class: `<td class="gallery"` and change the query: `$('.gallery a').lightBox();`